# .Animate() on dynamically generated content

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, jquery-animate

I am creating a website where I append progress-bar to div from JSON file.
Everything is working fine, but I can't figure out how to animate all progress-bar with their own value.

These values are loaded from the JSON file and I am only able to animate them all to one value not to their own one.

Code :

```
$.getJSON( "skills.json", function(data){
  Skills = data;

  $.each(Skills, function (title, val) {
  var markup = "<div class='progress-item'>";
  markup += "<span class='progress-title'>" + val.title + "</span>";
  markup += "<div class='progress'>";
  markup += "<div class='progress-bar'" + "style=width:" + val.value + "%" + ">" + "<span class='progress-percent'>" + val.value + "%" + "</span></div>";
  markup += "</div>";
  markup += "</div>";
  $('.progress-wrapper').append(markup);
  });
});
```

So this generates 3 progress-bar cause I have 3 values in my JSON file.

I tried something like :

```
$(".progress-bar").animate({width: val.value +"%"});
```

But it change the width of all my progress-bar even if they got all different in the JSON object.

JSON file :

```
[{
    "title": "Skill 1",
    "description": "Skill 1 description",
    "value": 100
},
{
    "title": "Skill 2",
    "description": "Skill 2 description",
    "value": 50
}
]
```

Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: What are the contents of that `skills.json` ? All the json values should go to 1 progress bar ? If so, how are they applied to it ?

Comment: I updated with part of the json file. Every titles get their own progress-bar so with this file there will be one with width:100 and another one width:50. Now I need all these width be animated when they load. First one from 0 to 100 and the second one from 0 to 50